# Folder cant be seen in Gallery

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, file-transfer

I m creating a hybrid app using Ionic. I created a folder in my DCIM folder of android where I save downloaded Images, Gifs.

Here is my code :

```
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
                    console.log("Root = " + fs.root.toURL() + "DCIM");
                   var entry=fs.root; entry.getDirectory("downloaded images", {create: true, exclusive: false},function (dirEntry) {  },function (error) { }
                                    );
                                }, function (error) {

                        });
                    });
```

Everything works fine. Only Problem is when I keep the foldername as "Downloaded_Images" or anything without space, I can see it in my android gallery , else the folder gets created but is not visible in gallery. But i need a folder with name "downloaded Images".

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var yourDirectory = decodeURIComponent(fs.root + "downloaded%20images");
```

Comment: Tried adding this and passing this variable in getDirectory , but no luck.

Comment: I found out that if I reboot or restart my phone, only then I see the folders in gallery. I dont know why my gallery doesnt get refreshed when I open it?

Comment: I solved it. while downloading Images, the path that is to be passed to filetransfer.download was modified.

Comment: while downloading Images, the path that is to be passed to filetransfer.download was modified.    var path =  fs.root.toURL() + "downloaded Images/ss.jpg"